# Next JS 14 with external backend Interceptors / Auth Token

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, jwt

I’m looking for the best practice to intercept server responses when using Next.js 14 with an external backend.

In my case, it’s Next.js 14 as a front-end app with a separate Node.js backend.

What I’m trying to figure out is the best practice for intercepting/handling use cases when the auth token is expired.

Initially I get the token on the client from Firebase Auth and then send it to the backend where I set cookies for the Next.js client. When making an API call thru server actions, I grab the token using 'cookies' from 'next/headers' and send it along with my request's. After one hour, the token expires. In my 'dashboard' route, I have an error.tsx page where I listen for an error message about the token expiration.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (error.message.includes('Firebase ID token has expired')) {
    getAuth()
      .currentUser?.getIdToken(true)
      .then(token => {
        refreshToken(token)
          .then(res => {
            if (res === 200) {
              router.refresh();
            }
          })
          .catch(error => console.log('Error refreshing token: ', error));
      });
  }
}, []);
```

In this hook I'm getting a new token and send it to the backend.

```
export const refreshToken = async (token: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${appConfig.BASE_URL}/create-session`, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      console.log("Couldn't refresh token");
    } else {
      revalidatePath('/dashboard');
      return response.status;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('refreshToken API call', error);
  }
};
```

Backend set new token as cookie on a client.
After all of this is done, I perform router.refresh and invalidate the route (just in case). In devtool, I can confirm that I got new token in cookies. However, the front end seems to be cached or not refreshed or I don't know what. It still keeps showing an error that the token is expired, and the API call returns with a 403 error. After I navigate between different pages a few times, Next.js somehow updates, and everything works fine for another 1 hour.

My question is: what am I doing wrong here, and what is the best practice to deal with these kinds of things?

Comment: `} catch (error) {
    console.log('refreshToken API call', error);
  }` does this get executed?